# Can't edit a state object passed in generic form component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components, react-component

I tried to create a generic component, based on object-properties I send to him where I can edit them through a TextInput element.

As you can see, I generate every textInput depending on the properties and I use an "onChange" event to make it works.
But, when I edit my object, it's like the copy's not working.
To be clear, I edit the object property value, but if I edit an other, the previous property will be reset.

Here's my main component :

```
const MainComponent= () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState({
        firstname: '',
        lastname:'',
        gender:'',
        age: 25 
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log({data});
    }, [data])

    return (
        <>
           <Form data={data} setData={setData} />
        </>
    )
}

export default MainComponent;
```

And here, my form component :

```
const Form = ({data, setData}) => {
    const [inputArr, setInputArr] = useState([]);

    const handleChange = (inputName) => (event) => {
        setData({
            ...data,
            [inputName]: event.target.name
        })
    }       

    const generateInputs = (obj) => {
        const arr = [];
        for(const props in obj) {
            arr.push(
                    <input type="text" onChange={() => handleChange(props)} value={data[`${props}`].toString()} />
            )
        }
        return arr;
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const res = generateInputs(data);
        setInputArr([...res]); 
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            {
                inputArr.map((item, index) => (
                    <div key={index}>
                        {item}
                    </div>
                ))
            }
        </>
    );
}

export default Form;
```

So, if someone has an idea ... thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
const Form = ({ data, setData }) => {
  const handleChange = (event, inputName) => {
    setData({ ...data, [inputName]: event.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {Object.keys(data).map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, item)}
              value={data[item]}
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

The main problems were the definition of your `handleChange` function, the way you passed (didn't pass) arguments to this function in your `onChange` and the way you passed data to the `value` prop of the inputs.

I also generally don't recommend saving markup to state. It is generally better to just save the state that is necessary to render your component.

[Sandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-oskar-e1vt5?file=/src/App.js:69-599)